# How do I code array and looping like SAS in R

Tags: r, arrays, sas

I have a process data in SAS and I stuck how to code in R.

The code seems like this:

```
data result; set check;
format Ti_Cycles_Delq_1 - Ti_Cycles_Delq_12 $1.;
array xxx{12} Ti_Cycles_Delq_1 - Ti_Cycles_Delq_12;
Do j=1 To 12;
a = substrn(delq12,j,1);
b = PUT(a,2.);
if a in ('Z' 'B' '1' '0') then xxx(j) = 0;
else xxx(j) = b-1;
end;
run;
```

I have sample data like this:

```
delq12 <- c('ZZZZZZBZZZZZ','Z1ZZZZZZZZZZ','ZZ2ZZZZ22ZZZ','ZZZ3ZZ4ZZZZ0')
```

I want the result like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified the names just so you can see the result more easily on one screen, but here's an attempt:

```
df <- data.frame(delq12 = c('ZZZZZZBZZZZZ','Z1ZZZZZZZZZZ','ZZ2ZZZZ22ZZZ','ZZZ3ZZ4ZZZZ0'))

n <- max(nchar(df$delq12))
vars <- paste0("Ti_", seq(n))
df[vars] <- read.fwf(textConnection(chartr("ZB10", "0000", df$delq12)), widths=rep(1, n))
df[vars] <- lapply(df[vars], \(x) pmax(0, x - 1) )

##        delq12 Ti_1 Ti_2 Ti_3 Ti_4 Ti_5 Ti_6 Ti_7 Ti_8 Ti_9 Ti_10 Ti_11 Ti_12
##1 ZZZZZZBZZZZZ    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
##2 Z1ZZZZZZZZZZ    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
##3 ZZ2ZZZZ22ZZZ    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0     0
##4 ZZZ3ZZ4ZZZZ0    0    0    0    2    0    0    3    0    0     0     0     0
```

The workhorse of the answer is `?read.fwf`, which converts each of the strings into separate columns for each character.

`chartr` translates the key characters into 0's prior to this, so that each of the columns are correctly guessed as integers.

Then it's just a matter of subtracting 1 from the values to get the final result.

Comment: can I ask, if I want to get the maximun from do looping but just to show the column max.
from the same data
data cek3;set cek;
do i = 1 to length(delq12);
X = substr(delq12,i,1);
if X in ('Z','B','1') then X = '0';
Y = put(X,2.);
MAX_DELQ = max(MAX_DELQ,Y);
end;
MAX_DELQ = max(MAX_DELQ-1,0);
run;

like I think maybe first  i make like you make and the new column for the max?
Thank you in advance